# How to parallelize running linear regressions on a GPU with pytorch

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, gpu, linear-regression

I am working on my Senior College Thesis and I need to calculate the Mean Squared Error between all possible pairs of roughly 7000 companies every year for the past 60 years, i.e. I need to run an enormous amount of regressions. The server that I have available has multiple very powerful GPU's, so I have implemented my linear regression code in pytorch. However, I am not very experienced in how to optimize my code in order to utilize the GPU to its fullest power, in particular how to run the code in parallel while on the GPU. Here is the for loop that is iterating over the company data, and I would greatly appreciate any advise or tips on how to code it such that it splits the jobs into optimal sizes.

--Note: I am aware that I am double counting pairs because (x,y)=(y,x), I still need to figure out how to implement this as well.

```py
for index_x,x in enumerate(unique_cusip_list):
    for index_y,y in enumerate(unique_cusip_list):
        
        #FIXME figure out how to not duplicate values 
            
        #FIXME figure out how to run it on the gpu
        
        #setting up the model parameters and inputs
        #------------------------------------------------------------#
        
        
        #adding the corresponding cusip pairs to our list 
        ids_list=[x,y]
        for val in ids_list:
            nested_list_outputs[total_iteration_counter].append(val)
            
        #preparing data
        x_values=nested_list_returns[index_x]
        y_values=nested_list_returns[index_y]
        
        #storing the number of ret variables given
        nested_list_outputs[total_iteration_counter].append(len(x_values))
        nested_list_outputs[total_iteration_counter].append(len(y_values))
        
        
        #if paired data doesnt match in length reduce larger dataset to fit the other
        if len(x_values)<len(y_values):
            y_values=y_values[:len(x_values)]
        if len(x_values)>len(y_values):
            x_values=x_values[:len(y_values)]
        
        #convserion to tensor variables 
        x_values_np=np.array(x_values,dtype=np.float32)
        x_values_np=x_values_np.reshape(-1,1)
        x_values_tensor=Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_values_np))
        
        
        y_values_np=np.array(y_values,dtype=np.float32)
        y_values_np=y_values_np.reshape(-1,1)
        y_values_tensor=Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_values_np))
        
        #move tensors to device
        x_values_tensor=x_values_tensor.to(device)
        y_values_tensor=y_values_tensor.to(device)
        
        if args.print_info:
            print('\n')
            print('Tensor shapes:')
            print(x_values_tensor.size())
            print(y_values_tensor.size())
            
            
            
        #defining the model 
        class LinearRegression(nn.Module):
            def __init__(self,input_size,output_size):
            # super function inherits from nn.Module so that we can access everything from nn.Module
                super(LinearRegression,self).__init__()
            # Linear function
                self.linear = nn.Linear(input_dim,output_dim)

            def forward(self,x):
                return self.linear(x)
        
        
        
        #defining model input and outputs:
        input_dim = 1
        output_dim = 1
        model = LinearRegression(input_dim, output_dim)
        
        #defining loss 
        mse=nn.MSELoss()
        
        #defining optimzation
        learning_rate = 0.01
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
        
        loss_list=[]
        
        num_epochs=100
        
        #send model to gpu
        if dev=='cuda:0':
            model.cuda()
        
        #training loop
        #------------------------------------------------------------#      

        for i in range(num_epochs):
            # perform optimization with zero gradient
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            results = model(x_values_tensor)
            loss = mse(results, y_values_tensor)

            # calculate derivative by stepping backward
            loss.backward()

            # Updating parameters
            optimizer.step()

            # store loss
            loss_list.append(loss.data)

            # print loss
            if args.print_info:
                if(i % 10 == 0):
                    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(i, loss.data))
            
        
        
        
        #save loss value    
        nested_list_outputs[total_iteration_counter].append(loss.data.item())
        
        
        #incriment loop counter
        total_iteration_counter+=1


end=time.time()
if args.print_outputs:
    for val in nested_list_outputs: 
        print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pytorch you can send any computing tasks to By using cuda() module.

First you need to set the device to GPU using the following command:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)
```

Similarly you can use:

```
model.to(torch.device('cuda:0'))
```

in this way you can send instructions to GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually already have done that, if cuda is available I am sending all my tensors to the gpu and my linear model also to the gpu, but the problem is, since each regression takes so little time to calculate, I dont think the gpu calculations are being optimized.